# Flash buttons flicker continuously when compiled

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I am looking for some help with Flash (CS5 version). I have a situation where if try to put a button on the stage with visible differences in the up/over/down/hit states, when I compile the document into a .swf, the button will continuously flicker through each state in order very quickly. Also, if I break the AS3 code in the Main class file, hidden parts of a slider bar component will flicker between visible and not. I'm talking Japanese-style, seizure-inducing flicker here. I've searched my code for recursive function calls and tried deleting and re-adding components and buttons, but to no avail. Any ideas on what could be up?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it seems to me you aren't using `stop()` to stop the button at the frame you want.

If it isn't this, then there is some error with your ActionScript, which will show up in the output panel, so check that.

Answer (score 2):

When you say 'button' is it an instance of the Button Class and have you set the instance type to Button?

i.e. 
Select the button in your library panel, right click and choose 'Properties'. Then set the Type to Button.

Next, select the instance of the button on the stage, open the Properties panel and just underneath where you type the instance name you should see a drop down menu containing MovieClip, Button and Graphic. Set it to Button.